# $\{∅\} ⊆ \{x\}$ Is this true (can also be written as $\{\{ \}\} ⊆ \{x\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is `{∅} ⊆ {x}` true or false?
I'm guessing it is false as empty-set within the set is not within the x set.
If it was `∅ ⊆ {x}` then it would be true.
Is this right?

Comment: If $x\neq\emptyset$ then $\emptyset\not\in\{x\}$, so $\{\emptyset\}\not\subseteq\{x\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. As $\varnothing \in \{\varnothing\}$ but $\varnothing \notin \{x\}$ (assuming $x$ is non-empty), we have $\{\varnothing\}\not\subseteq \{x\}$.

We also do have $\varnothing \subseteq \{x\}$, because there is no element $y\in \varnothing$ which can serve as a witness that it is false.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=\emptyset$, then $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq\{x\}$ is true. If $x\ne\emptyset$, then it is false. On the other hand, $\emptyset\subseteq A$ is true for any set $A$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true if and only if $x=\emptyset$ since $\{x\}$ has only one element.

$\emptyset \subseteq \{x\}$ is true because the empty set is a subset of every set.

Your second sentence is confusing.